# CSS Not Applied to Element Dynamically Added with JQuery

Tags: javascript, popover

I do this in my javascript code:

```
$("#m_modal_6 .modal-body").append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-popover" data-trigger="hover" data-skin="dark" data-toggle="m-popover" data-placement="bottom" title="Dark skin" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Dark skin</button>');
```

In my document ready i do this to show up the popover:

```
$('.m-popover').popover('show');
```

I have classes in css with dark skin that works in html but when i add this with append function the dark skin and other style doesn't work ..

Comment: So you are showing the popover before you append it?

Comment: $('#m_modal_6').on("shown.bs.modal", function() , after i show the modal

Comment: you are adding css for `btn`?

Comment: Your porblme could be, your CSS is not applied to body.  The popovr appends its container to to body.

Comment: data-skin is the key here .. when i use simple in html it works but when i use append in javascript it doesn't work anymore ..

Answer (score -1):

JQuery will select all current elements with class `.m-popover` when `$(".m-popover")` is called. The problem is that you append the object after you modify `.m-popover` selector. `document.ready` will be called after the other script has loaded. I would do the following:

```
let obj = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-popover" data-trigger="hover" data-skin="dark" data-toggle="m-popover" data-placement="bottom" title="Dark skin" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">Dark skin</button>');
obj.popover('show');
$("#m_modal_6 .modal-body").append(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I put into practice your idea but still i get the same style ..